# No '-addSubView' method found

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I get "no '-addSubView' method found "

when I try to add a subview to a window, in this case trying to add a button. Here is my code

```
@interface SBUIController 

-(id)window;

@end


@interface SBAwayView 

-(void)chargingView;
-(void)showChargingView;
-(void)hideChargingView;
-(void)showBulletinView;
-(BOOL)shouldShowChargingView;
-(void)hideCameraButton;

@end

%hook SBAwayController

-(void)_tearDownCameraPreview{

//SBAwayView *v = MSHookIvar<id>(self, //"_awayView");

UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; myButton.frame = CGRectMake(21, 80, 100, 35); [myButton setTitle:@"My Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

SBUIController *ui = MSHookIvar<id>(self, "_uiController");


[[ui window] addSubView:myButton];

%orig; }

%end
```

Comment: What is this `MSHookIvar(self, "_uiController");` stuff?!

Comment: MS = MobileSubstrate, a patching framework (for jailbroken devices). http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate

Comment: The method name does not have a capital "V" in `view`, it's `-addSubView;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is called `addSubview:`, not `addSubView:`.

```
[[ui window] addSubview:myButton];
```